# .Master extension request is filtered in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config

I have tried running the .Master extension page and am getting the following error

> "Request filtering is configured for the Web server and the file extension for this request is explicitly denied."

I have already tried,

1.Setting the requset filtering true for .Master is IIS,

2.Added following to Web.config file,

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true">
      <remove fileExtension="." />
      <add fileExtension="." allowed="true" />
    </fileExtensions>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

3.And also verified that the " fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true" in applicationhost.config file,

4..aspx files are working fine only promblem seems to be with master page

Could you please suggest what could be the problem here?

Comment: Why are you even trying to run this directly? Your aspx pages will reference the master page and display the contents accordingly.